# Add Safecontrol assembly in web.config through powershell

Tags: powershell

Can any one guide me in powershell to add safecontrol assembly in sharepoint web app web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the code provided here - [Modify SafeControls in web.config using Powershell script leveraging SPWebConfigModification method](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ada87738-c98f-4c1c-af3e-29b14feb67a2/modify-safecontrols-in-webconfig-using-powershell-script-leveraging-spwebconfigmodification-method?forum=sharepointadmin)

```
#SafeControl

$assembly = " Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"

$namespace = "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages "

$mod = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification

$mod.Name = "SafeControls"

$mod.Path = "configuration/SharePoint/SafeControls"

$mod.Owner = "Contoso"

$mod.Type = 0 #for the enum value "SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode"

$mod.Value = '<SafeControl Assembly="{0}" Namespace="{1}" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />' -f $assembly, $namespace

$app.WebConfigModifications.Add($mod)

#applying changes

$service = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService

$service.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

$app.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$assembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\temp\TestWebPartLibrary.dll") 
$name = $assembly.GetName() 
"<SafeControl Assembly=""{0}"" Namespace=""{1}"" TypeName=""*"" />" -f $assembly.FullName,$assembly.GetName().Name
```

http://www.justaddcode.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-sharepoints-safecontrol-entries-in-powershell/